# What does "if" mean in "if simply because of"?

Tags: word-meaning, difference

I encountered the following sentence in my linguistics textbook:

> FMRI is not generally applicable to infants awake at these ages, if
> simply because of the mechanical requirements, which require no
> movement.

The meaning of "if" here seems not to indicate a condition (as in "I will go outside if it's sunny"), so the questions are:

1. What is the meaning of "if" in the quoted sentence from my textbook?
2. What would be the difference if "if" were removed from the sentence?

Answer (score 2):

You are splitting the sentence in the wrong place, and should consider the phrase 'if simply because' to be a fixed phrase (alternatively, 'if only because'). It is used when saying that something may be true for more than one reason, but only one is being mentioned. This reason may be the most important one, and is usually a main or decisive one, so that mentioning the others is not necessary.

> FMRI is not generally applicable to infants awake at these ages, for
> this decisive reason, although there may be others: there are mechanical requirements, which specify no movement (young infants may not be able to keep still).

Riding in a car driven by John is not wise, *if simply because* he is blind (he may also not have a driving licence, be drunk, intend suicide, etc).